# can we install sharepoint 2013 on my windows 8 O.S?

Tags: sharepoint, windows-8

Am a budding sharepoint developer and just getting started wit it,I want to explore sharepoint and create basic web applications,asI dont know the installation criteria.Help me with it.Thanks in advance and I again mention am a beginer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially, [no, it is intended for Server OS's only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869(v=office.15).aspx#SP15_bk_InstallOS). Unofficially, this is possible. These were some notes I made along the way of installing SFS on a 64 bit Windows 8.1 Pro with 8GB RAM (for a proof of concept - Customer had applicable server licenses, but no Dev Environment, FWR).

1. PC must be on a domain
2. Install this hack :  http://www.disruptivei.com/Blogg/Inl%C3%A4gg/6/Install-SharePoint-2013-on-Windows-7-8-8-1
3. Download 2013 Foundation SP1: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42039
4. Ensure all the prerequisites are set up - (IIS, WIF, Http and Tcp activation), ensure Services are restarted.
5. Make sure you extract the exe using the built in extractor, not 7Zip:
   Otherwise you get an `unsupported language pack error`

Some other links I needed along the way:

http://techblurt.com/2009/11/30/sharepoint-2010-the-language-of-this-installation-package-is-not-supported-by-your-system/http://techblurt.com/2009/11/30/sharepoint-2010-the-language-of-this-installation-package-is-not-supported-by-your-system/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155805/Install-Sharepoint-2010-in-a-non-Server-OS